# Disable Insert Worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Is there a way to prevent people from inserting worksheets manually. I have a form that creates the worksheets automatically based on the information the user puts in it. The code I currently uses will prevent people from creating worksheets but it also prevents my form from creating worksheets. Here is what I am using. It is in the workbook module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sh.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare this in a Module

```
Public BoolAdd As Boolean
```

This in your `Workbook_NewSheet`

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If BoolAdd = False Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sh.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Else
        BoolAdd = False
    End If
End Sub
```

and set the `BoolAdd` to `TRUE` in your userform before you add the sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    BoolAdd = True
    Sheets.Add
End Sub
```

**Logic**: The userform will set the public variable to `True`. This will ensure that sheet deletion code will not run. Also we have to set it back to false else the user will be able to add the sheet after the userform is closed.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Sidd!

Comment: +1 excellent answer. works if multiple sheets are inserted as well.